# Custom Category Fields

Tags: categories

Hmm, taking my first steps with categories and not having much joy.

I've got {meta-title} and {meta-description} category fields set up for each category. Having trouble pulling back the correct data for the category, just pulls back the first categories custom category fields.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{product_channel}" category_group="1"}
    {categories} 
        <title>{meta-title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{meta-description}" />
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Lows Seg2Cat to get the category ID. Thanks Low!

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{product_channel}" category_group="1" category="{last_segment_category_id}"}
        {categories}
            <title>{meta-title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content="{meta-description}" />
        {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```